# import excel using chunck filter php

Tags: php

I have tried to import excel using PHP excel Library. It is working for small data .But it is not working with excel containing more than 30000 rows .I have tried increase memory limit and execution time.It is also taking long time.
here is my code

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('max_input_time', -1);
 
$fileName = $_FILES["production"]["tmp_name"];
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);
$phpspreadsheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
                 
$total_data = $phpspreadsheet->getHighestRow();
//echo $chunkSize;
// exit;
$highest_column = $phpspreadsheet->getHighestColumn();

for ($row = 2 ; $row <= $total_data; $row++) {
    $productionDataAll = $phpspreadsheet-> rangeToArray ('A' . $row . ':' . $highest_column . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
                        
    $line           =htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][0]);
    $workedorder    =htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][1]);
    $modelnumber    =htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][2]);
    $revision       =htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][3]);
    if(!empty($productionDataAll[0][4])){
        $serialnumber = htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][4]);
    }else{
        $serialnumber='';
    }
    $lpn            = htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][5]);
    $shift          = htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][6]);
    $datecreated    = htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][7]);
    $datecompleted  = htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][8]);
    $repairflag     = htmlentities($productionDataAll[0][9]);
    $date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
    $skeydate       = date("Ymd", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
    $skey           = $skeydate.$line;
    $importproduction = importproduction(
                                    $mysql_connectionLinkLocal, 
                                    $line, 
                                    $workedorder, 
                                    $modelnumber, 
                                    $revision,
                                    $serialnumber,
                                    $lpn,
                                    $shift,
                                    $repairflag,
                                    $date,
                                    $skey,
                                    $datecreated,
                                    $datecompleted); 
}
```

I have tried to use chunck filter . But it is not working .How to add  chunck filter with above code ?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: _I have tried increase memory limit and execution time_ Why, did the script crash with errors that indicated these parameters were too low? Is that still the problem?

Comment: You might want to look into https://github.com/box/spout for your use case. PHPExcel is a memory hog when you deal with a lot of data (rows/columns).

Comment: We do not really know what you problem is. If you describe the problem, someone here may well be able to advise you of a solution, rather than you suggesting what you think might be a good idea

Comment: There is also a new version of phpExcel called phpSpreadsheet, a rewrite by the original author I believe

Comment: What have you done when you tried chunck filter? What happened then? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I have tried below code  ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= $total_data; $startRow += $chunkSize) { $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow, $chunkSize); but it is not working. for ($row = 2 ; $row <= $total_data; $row++) is reading upto end of the row in sheet .How to read first 1000 data and then read  next  1000 up to end of the row in sheet .